# How likely is it to get a HashCode collision with this hashcode function?

Tags: c#, data-structures, hashcode

How likely is it to get a HashCode collision with the function below in following scenarios.

1. With random int values for key[0],key[1], key[2], key[3]
2. With random key values with the following constraints

   - key[0] <1,000,000
   - key[1] <10,000
   - key[2] <1,000
   - key[3] <1,000

Assume we have 10 Million objects.

```
int[] key=new int[4];    
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    // Use large prime multiples to create a unique hash key
    // Create the hash offsets using a "even powers of 2 minus 1" method, which gives 
    // primes most of the time.  
    int hashKey = 0;
    hashKey += 2047 * key[0];
    hashKey += 8191 * key[1];
    hashKey += 32767 * key[2];
    hashKey += 131071 * key[3];
    return hashKey;
}
```

Comment: nope. real life. that's our hash function and we are trying to solve much bigger problems now. Trying to assess how big of an issue this will be.

Comment: In what situation then is .NET's built in GetHashCode() insufficient? I've never found an issue where it didn't correctly differentiate objects.

Comment: @Tejs The built in `GetHashCode` is based on referential equality(for reference types only of course). If you want value equality you need to override it(together with `.Equals`). So I don't really understand what the point you're making is.

Comment: I was just curious, as I've never seen an example where it is needed. It's also why I'm not answering as I'm curious about the answer.

Comment: @Tejs I need it quite often. Many of my classes are immutable and have value semantics. `Tuple<...>` and anonymous types need such compound hashes too.

Comment: @Tejs The real issue is we do some preprocessing after which we store some precalculated values based on this hashcode in the database. Threads running after the preprocess are trying to get the correct values based on their key values and generated hashCode.

Comment: in practice what you're interested in are collisions in `Dictionary<T>`. Which if I recall correctly first masks out the sign bit, and then takes hash%capacity with a prime capacity. So I'd look into the implementation of `Dictionary` and check if there is no collision between the primes MS uses, and the ones you use.

Comment: @derdo you might consider using a `Tuple<int,int,int,int>`. Not sure if it fits what you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote a quick script to test this.

```
import random

def hash(key):
    hashKey = 0
    hashKey += 2047 * key[0]
    hashKey += 8191 * key[1]
    hashKey += 32767 * key[2]
    hashKey += 131071 * key[3]
    return hashKey

seen = set()
collisions = 0
for i in range(0,10000000):
    x = hash([random.randint(0,1000000), random.randint(0,10000), random.randint(0,1000), random.randint(0,1000)])
    if x in seen:
        collisions += 1
    else:
        seen.add(x)

print collisions
```

When I ran it, it told me I got 23735 collisions.
I also tried it on one million elements, and I got 247 collisions. Both numbers are averages over 4 runs.

Comment: Hard to see what this proves, other than the Birthday Paradox.

Comment: @Hans: It answers the original question exactly; what else would it need to prove?

Answer (score 9):

This is kind of a strange question. Let's start with the obvious errors in the code:

```
// Use large prime multiples to create a unique hash key     
// Create the hash offsets using a "even powers of 2 minus 1" method, which gives      
// primes most of the time.
```

First off, those are all odd powers of two minus one; none of them are even powers of two minus one.

Second, of the four multipliers you've chosen as "large prime multiples", half of them are not prime. 2047 and 32767 are composite.

Third, if we "correct" -- and I use the word advisedly -- the statement to be "odd powers of 2 minus one which gives primes most of the time" that statement is *absurdly* wrong. A prime of that form is known as a Mersenne prime, and **there are only 47 known Mersenne primes**.  I assure you that the density of Mersenne primes is considerably lower than one half. Put it this way: of the odd-power Mersenne numbers between 2^1-1 and 2^43112609−1, 46 of them are known to be prime numbers, which is about one in a half a million, not half.

Fourth, what do you imagine prime numbers have to do with anything?  What mythological power do prime numbers have?  Surely what matters is that the distribution of hash codes tends to not produce multiples of the hash table size. Since the hash table size is *chosen to be a prime number*, it seems like this is potentially *exacerbating* the problem.

Fifth, hash keys are not unique; your question is about when they collide, so clearly they cannot be unique.

Sixth, suppose your hash function had a *perfectly random* distribution across the space of 32 bit integers. By the birthday "paradox" you'd expect there to be a far greater than 99% chance of at least one collision when drawing ten million numbers at random from a 32 bit space. In fact, the expected number of collisions would be on the order of ten or twenty thousand.  (We could work out the exact number of expected collisions, but who cares what it is exactly; it is in that order of magnitude.)

Is that too many collisions? It is going to be very difficult to do better than a random distribution.  If you require fewer collisions than that, then you shouldn't be using a 32 bit hashing algorithm in the first place.

Seventh, who cares how many collisions a hash function has across its full range? Surely the practical question ought to really be "how does this hash perform with realistic data in a large table?"  You, unlike us, can answer that question by *trying it*.  If it meets your performance budget, great, worry about something else. If it doesn't, figure out why not before you start blaming the hash function.

I am very confused by this question and what you hope to gain from its answer. Can you explain?

Comment: Hey thanks for the detailed answer. I guess my question has demonstrated that comments lie:) Thanks also for the detailed corrections. Without going into too much detail, the more collisions I get, the worse is the performance of my optimization algorithm which optimizes some pseudo profit function. Due to the way our optimization works less number of collisions in that hash function means that the result is closer to the theoretical optimal. If they are unique I am guaranteed the best result. I was trying to assess do I need a different solution now (huge amount of collisions) or can I wait.

Comment: So I was really practical and tried to keep the question to the exact thing I was interested in without creating confusion or spending too much time. Sorry for the confusion and the wrong comments in the code again.

Comment: @derdo: Are you using the hash function for something *other* than balancing a hash table? **Don't do that**. GetHashCode is designed to produce reasonable balancing of bucket sizes when stuffing a few thousand things into an in-memory hash table; it is not designed to produce optimal, collision-free hashing on large data sets. I note that by the statement of your problem there are only 10^16 = 2^54 possible values. Can you generate a unique 64 bit hash? Doing so is trivial.

Comment: Yes, we are using the GetHashCode to create optimization groups. Products in the same optimization group gets optimized together and result might a bit worse than optimizing them individually. It was very handy when the problem size is small with little probability of collision. Now looks like I need something else and might try 64 bit hash.

Comment: @derdo: I think a 64 bit hash is the way to go. Clearly you can just convert to long and multiply each field by 1000000, 10000000000, etc, add the results together, and you'll have a unique 64 bit number. FYI, the way to work out how many repeats are expected when choosing n numbers from a set of size d is (n - d + (d) x (d-1/d)^n). If you choose n to be 10^16 and d to be 2^32 you'll see that the expected number of collisions based on bad luck alone is around 10-20 thousand.

Comment: Excellent response! Just out of interest, by using tailor series approximation 1 - e^( (-n ( n -1))/2*2^32), where n the number of repetitions we can see that for n=78000 there is approx a 50% chance of a collision on a 32bit hashcode space (given a random implementation of hashcode) This number rises to 5 billion when a 64bit hashcode is used. Hence, a set of 5 billion using a 64 bit random hashcode function has a 50% chance of collision...

Answer (score 2):

I was going to say you should use

```
int hashKey = key[0].GetHashCode();
hashKey ^= key[1].GetHashCode();
hashKey ^= key[2].GetHashCode();
hashKey ^= key[3].GetHashCode();
```

as it would give better results, but when I tested it I was thoroughly surprised. Posting the results anyway because as a scientist "results you did not expect are still results".

Collisions1 is your method, Collisions2 is my method, this is the results of 4 runs

```
Collisions1: 23744
Collisions2: 8996107

Collisions1: 23825
Collisions2: 8996215

Collisions1: 23771
Collisions2: 8996119

Collisions1: 24031
Collisions2: 8996157
```

Comment: Think about what xor does on integers that are close to each other. Does that give you an insight as to why you have so many collisions? xor is almost always a bad idea because its output is only well distributed if its operands are well-distributed **and not correlated**.  A good hash function should give good results even if its inputs are correlated.

Comment: @Eric Lippert, I would have agree with you if i had not called GetHashCode() on each but I assumed (incorrectly) that calling GetHashCode() would give me a well-distributed and not correlated restult.

Comment: Right -- GetHashCode of an int just returns the int.