# Dictionary <,> Size , GetHashCode and Prime Numbers?

Tags: c#, .net, math, dictionary

*I've been reading quite a lot about this interesting topic (IMO). but I'm not fully understand one thing :*

Dictionary size is increasing its capacity  ( *doubles to the closest prime number*) to  a prime number (when reallocation) : 
because :

```
int index = hashCode % [Dictionary Capacity];
```

- So we can see that prime numbers are used here  for `[Dictionary Capacity]` because their *GreatestCommonFactor*  is `1`. and this *helps* to avoid collisions.

**In addition**

I've seen many samples of implementing the`GetHashCode()` :

Here is a sample from Jon Skeet :

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    unchecked 
    {
        int hash = 17;
        // Suitable nullity checks etc, of course :)
        hash = hash * 23 + field1.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash * 23 + field2.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash * 23 + field3.GetHashCode();
        return hash;
    }
}
```

I don't understand :

**Question**

> Does prime numbers are used   **both** in : `Dictionary capacity`
>   **and** in the generation of `getHashCode`  ?

Because in the code above , there is a good chance that the return value will *not* be a prime number [*please correct me if i'm wrong*] because of the

- multiplication by `23`
- addition of the `GetHashCode()` value for each field.

For Example : (11,17,173 are prime number)

```
        int hash = 17;
        hash = hash * 23 + 11; //402
        hash = hash * 23 + 17; //9263
        hash = hash * 23 + 173 //213222
        return hash;
```

213222 is not a prime.

Also there is not any math rule which state :

`(not a prime number) + (prime number) = (prime number)`

nor

`(not a prime number) * (prime number) = (prime number)`

nor

`(not a prime number) * (not a prime number) = (prime number)`

So **what** am I missing ?

Comment: where did you see this GetHashCode implementation ?

Comment: @Tigran http://stackoverflow.com/a/263416/859154

Comment: I never read anywhere that hash codes should be prime, or even that it is better if they are prime - what they should be is as evenly distributed as possible over their entire range.

Comment: See Eric Lippert's answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5331842/how-likely-is-it-to-get-a-hashcode-collision-with-this-hashcode-function

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It does not matter what the result of `GetHashCode` is (it does not have to be prime at all), as long as the result is the same for two objects that are considered to be equal. However, it is *nice* (but not required) to have `GetHashCode` return a different value for two objects that are considered to be different (but still not necessarily prime).

Given two numbers *a* and *b*, when you multiply them you get `c = a * b`. There are usually multiple different pairs of *a* and *b* that give the same result *c*. For example 6 * 2 = 12 and 4 * 3 = 12. However, when *a* is a *prime* number, there are a lot less pairs that give the same result. This is convenient for the property that the hash code should be *different* for different objects.

In the dictionary the same principle applies: the objects are put in buckets depending on their hash. Since most integers do not divide nicely by a prime number, you get a nice spreading of your objects in the buckets. Ideally you'd want only one item in each bucket for optimal dictionary performance.

---

Slightly off-topic: Cicada's (that's an insect) [use prime numbers](http://io9.com/5895840/why-do-cicadas-know-prime-numbers) to determine after how many years they go and mate again. Since this mating cycle is a *prime* number of years, the chances of the mating continously coinciding with the life cycles of any of its enemies are slim.

Comment: @Virtlink: + 1 bit me on cicadas, didn't know that. Absolutely out of topic, but straordinary beautiful. Already posted on G+.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Humans like to make parallels between their knowledge and observations arround them (look on Dan Brown: Da Vinci Code, for example), but this one is actualy the *nature* that leads us to that conclusion. Is it correct or not, noone knows.

Comment: @Virtlink -(offtopic) Isn't a fly live for a week max ? how come _years_ got in here ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir Apparently this species (which isn't technically a fly) lives for years. But don't ask be about specifics, I only read it in the linked article. I am mostly human, partly programmer, and certainly not an entomologist. :P

Comment: You said: *most integers do not divide nicely by a prime number*. And I say: for each prime `P`, there is the same or less number of integers that "divide nicely" by `P+1`.